# How to apply a function on a sequential data within group in spark?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a custom function which is depended on the order of the data. I want to apply this function for each group in spark in parallel (parallel groups). How can I do?

For example,

```
public ArrayList<Integer> my_logic(ArrayList<Integer> glist) {
    Boolean b = true;
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1; i<glist.size();I++) {  // Size is around 30000
        If b && glist[i-1] > glist[i] {
            // some logic then set b to false
            result.add(glist[i]);
        } else {
           // some logic then set b to true
        }
    }
 return result;
}
```

My data,

```
Col1  Col2
a        1
b        2
a        3
c        4
c        3
….      ….
```

I want something similar to below

```
df.group_by(col(“Col1”)).apply(my_logic(col(“Col2”))); 
// output
a     [1,3,5…]
b     [2,5,8…]
….   ….
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, you can use Window Aggregate Functions directly, I will show that here in Scala.

Here is your input data (my preparation):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val schema = StructType(
    StructField("Col1", StringType, false) ::
    StructField("Col2", IntegerType, false) :: Nil
)

val row = Seq(Row("a", 1),Row("b", 8),Row("b", 2),Row("a", 5),Row("b", 5),Row("a", 3))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(row, schema)
df.show(false)
//input:
// +----+----+
// |Col1|Col2|
// +----+----+
// |a   |1   |
// |b   |8   |
// |b   |2   |
// |a   |5   |
// |b   |5   |
// |a   |3   |
// +----+----+
```

Here is the code to obtain desired logic :

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
  df
// NEWCOLUMN: EVALUATE/CREATE LIST OF VALUES FOR EACH RECORD OVER THE WINDOW AS FRAME MOVES
    .withColumn(
      "collected_list",
      collect_list(col("Col2")) over Window
        .partitionBy(col("Col1"))
        .orderBy(col("Col2"))
    )
// NEWCOLUMN: MAX SIZE OF COLLECTED LIST IN EACH WINDOW
    .withColumn(
      "max_size",
      max(size(col("collected_list"))) over Window.partitionBy(col("Col1"))
    )
// FILTER TO GET ONLY HIGHEST SIZED ARRAY ROW
    .where(col("max_size") - size(col("collected_list")) === 0)
    .orderBy(col("Col1"))
    .drop("Col2", "max_size")
    .show(false)

// output:
// +----+--------------+
// |Col1|collected_list|
// +----+--------------+
// |a   |[1, 3, 5]     |
// |b   |[2, 5, 8]     |
// +----+--------------+
```

Note:

1. you can just use collect_list() Aggregate function with groupBy directly but, you can not get the collection list ordered.
2. collect_set() Aggregate function you can explore if you want to eliminate duplicates (with some changes to the above query).

###### EDIT 2 : You can write your custom collect_list() as a UDAF (UserDefinedAggregateFunction) like this in Scala Spark for DataFrames

###### Online Docs

1. [For Spark2.3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction)
2. [For Latest Version](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html)

###### Below Code Spark Version == 2.3.0

```
object Your_Collect_Array extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

    override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(
      StructField("yourInputToAggFunction", LongType, false) :: Nil
    )

    override def dataType: ArrayType = ArrayType(LongType, false)

    override def deterministic: Boolean = true

    override def bufferSchema: StructType = {
      StructType(
        StructField("yourCollectedArray", ArrayType(LongType, false), false) :: Nil
      )
    }
    override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
      buffer(0) = new Array[Long](0)
    }

    override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {

      buffer.update(
        0,
        buffer.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0) :+ input.getLong(0)
      )

    }

    override def merge(
        buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer,
        buffer2: Row
    ): Unit = {
      buffer1.update(
        0,
        buffer1.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0) ++ buffer2
          .getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0)
      )

    }
    override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any =
      buffer.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0)

  }


//Below is the query with just one line change i.e., calling above written custom udf 
df
// NEWCOLUMN : USING OUR CUSTOM UDF
  .withColumn(
    "your_collected_list",
    Your_Collect_Array(col("Col2")) over Window
      .partitionBy(col("Col1"))
      .orderBy(col("Col2"))
  )
// NEWCOLUMN: MAX SIZE OF COLLECTED LIST IN EACH WINDOW
  .withColumn(
    "max_size",
    max(size(col("your_collected_list"))) over Window.partitionBy(col("Col1"))
  )
// FILTER TO GET ONLY HIGHEST SIZED ARRAY ROW
  .where(col("max_size") - size(col("your_collected_list")) === 0)
  .orderBy(col("Col1"))
  .drop("Col2", "max_size")
  .show(false)

//Output:
// +----+-------------------+
// |Col1|your_collected_list|
// +----+-------------------+
// |a   |[1, 3, 5]          |
// |b   |[2, 5, 8]          |
// +----+-------------------+
```

Note:

1. UDFs are not that efficient in spark hence, use them only when you absolutely need them. They are mainly focused for data analytics.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me in understanding why we need the max_size column and also how can I call my custom udf on the collected_list column. Basically, I want to get the insert ordered list as collected_list column and then apply my own custom function. The custom function should return a new list

Comment: @Selva
I have updated my answer above.
to answer your other questions 1) max_size is to just filter out all other rows that do not have all the aggregation in a single window frame ie., to keep only that row whose collect_list size is max later.
2) you can similarly write your UDFs based on the one I have shown you, read more about them online to understand how they work.
3) Spark is distributed, you can not plugin something that easily to take care of everything for you so, you have to extend UDFs to write your own by overriding available methods in them.